# SQL query to find the length of the serie of values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need a query that evaluates the longest uninterrupted series of subsequent "1"'s in the column `FL_SUCC_EXEC`. For the following data in table `TEST(row_no number, fl_succ_exec number(1))`, the result of the query should be "6".

Rows are ordered by `row_no`.

```
    ROW_NO   FL_SUCC_EXEC
---------- ------------
         1            1
         2            1
         3            1
         4            0
         5            1
         6            1
         7            1
         8            1
         9            1
        10            1
        11            0                               
        12            1
        13            1
        14            1  
        15            1
```

I can do this in PL/SQL :

```
declare
temp_cnt pls_integer default 0;
total_cnt pls_integer default 0;
begin
for rec in (select row_no, fl_succ_exec from test order by row_no)
loop
  if temp_cnt > total_cnt
   then 
   total_cnt:=temp_cnt;
  end if;

  if rec.fl_succ_exec!=0 
  then
     temp_cnt:=temp_cnt+rec.fl_succ_exec;
  else
     temp_cnt:=0;
  end if;

end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(total_cnt);
end;
```

But I'm still hoping for SQL solution. Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT max( count(*) ) As longest_uninterrupted_series
FROM (
    select fl_succ_exec,
           sum( case when fl_succ_exec = 1 then 0 else 1 end ) 
              over ( order by row_no ) xx 
    from test
)
WHERE fl_succ_exec = 1
GROUP BY xx;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( row_no, fl_succ_exec ) AS
  SELECT  1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  6, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  7, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  9, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT MAX( num_1s ) AS num_1s
FROM   (
  SELECT COALESCE(
           row_no - LAST_VALUE( CASE fl_succ_exec WHEN 0 THEN row_no END )
                      IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY row_no ),
           ROWNUM
         ) AS num_1s
  FROM   test
);
```

**Output**:

```
NUM_1S
------
     6
```